# How fix Cyclic dependency found without disabling constraints?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm working on a database for my game and this is how I designed my database for storing which character owns which item.

The models:
**Characters Model:**

```
sequelize.define('characters', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true
        }
        primary_slot: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        secondary_slot: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        armor_slot: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        }
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true
    });
```

**Items Model:**

```
sequelize.define('items', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    damage: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0
    }
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false
  });
```

The relations between the `Characters` and `Items` models is a many-to-many relation through the `item_ownerships` table:

```
Characters.belongsToMany(models.items, {
    through: 'item_ownerships', 
    foreignKey: 'owner_id',
    otherKey: 'item_id'
});

Items.belongsToMany(models.characters, {
    through: 'item_ownerships', 
    foreignKey: 'item_id',
    otherKey: 'owner_id'
});
```

**Item_ownerships model:**

```
sequelize.define('item_ownerships', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    owner_id: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    item_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    durability: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }
```

As seen below, I've added an extra `id` column to the `item_ownerships` table because I want each entry in that table to have a unique ID as a primary key instead of the primary key being a composite key of the 2 foreign keys `owner_id` and `item_id`.

Now here comes my issue, I want to define the following associations:

```
Item_ownerships.hasOne(models.characters, {
    foreignKey: 'primary_slot'
});

Item_ownerships.hasOne(models.characters, {
    foreignKey: 'secondary_slot'
});

Item_ownerships.hasOne(models.characters, {
    foreignKey: 'armor_slot'
});


Characters.belongsTo(models.item_ownerships, {
    foreignKey: 'primary_slot'
});
Characters.belongsTo(models.item_ownerships, {
    foreignKey: 'secondary_slot'
});
Characters.belongsTo(models.item_ownerships, {
    foreignKey: 'armor_slot'
});
```

Meaning, I want the `primary_slot` column of a character to hold the ID (foreignKey) of an ownership of an item in the `item_ownerships` table.
The error I get is the following:
`Sequelize: Cyclic dependency found. Dependency chain: characters -> item_ownerships => characters`

Adding `constraints: false` isn't the course of action here because then I don't have the foreignkey constraints. I want a character to only be able to `equip` an item that they own in the `item_ownerships` table.

EDIT: Fixed typos

Answer (score 0):

You should add aliases to all associations that are between the same models to let Sequelize distinguish them from each other:

```
Items.hasOne(models.md_characters, {
    foreignKey: 'primary_slot',
    as: 'PrimarySlot'
});

Items.hasOne(models.md_characters, {
    foreignKey: 'secondary_slot',
    as: 'SecondarySlot'
});

Items.hasOne(models.md_characters, {
    foreignKey: 'armor_slot',
    as: 'ArmorSlot'
});

MD_characters.belongsTo(models.item_ownerships, {
    foreignKey: 'primary_slot',
    as: 'PrimaryOwnership'
});
MD_characters.belongsTo(models.item_ownerships, {
    foreignKey: 'secondary_slot',
    as: 'SecondaryOwnership'
});
MD_characters.belongsTo(models.item_ownerships, {
    foreignKey: 'armor_slot',
    as: 'ArmorOwnership'
});
```

Comment: I made a typo on the post. In the code, instead of `Items.hasOne` I used `Item_ownerships.hasOne` so that wasn't the issue unfortunately..

Comment: But `Item_ownerships.hasOne` make no sense because their PK is not related with `primary_slot` column at all.The same goes for `MD_characters.belongsTo(models.item_ownerships`

Comment: How do you mean they are not related at all? The PK from `item_ownerships` should be a foreign key in the `MD_characters` (or rather `Characters`) table.
The `primary_slot`, `secondary_slot` and `armor` columns reference the PK in `item_ownerships`. At least, that's what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Can you add `manyToMany` associatins to the post as well?

Comment: I rewrote my answer

Comment: I tried adding aliases but I still get: `Error: Cyclic dependency found. md_characters is dependent of itself.
Dependency chain: md_characters -> item_ownerships => md_characters`

Comment: In that case you should indicate `constraints: false` in association(s) from one side, see https://sequelize.org/master/manual/constraints-and-circularities.html

Comment: Adding `constraints: false` to one model association didn't change anything. If I add them to both then the error disappears but like I said, that disables that FK which I want to avoid (as specified in the title).

Comment: Does `Item_ownerships` have records other then `primary`, `secondary` and `armor`?

Comment: What exactly to you mean by records? It has 2 foreign keys `owner_id` and `item_id`, one from the `characters` table and one from the `items` table respectively.

Comment: I mean how many records in `Item_ownerships` one character has?

Comment: Anything between 0-100 but currently 0 while developing, if I understood your question properly..

Comment: Hmm. I'm out of ideas. Maybe you should rethink your DB structure to achieve your goal.

Comment: Side question, is it possible to disable the unique constraint on the composite key in `item_ownerships` so that the only constraint present in that model is the Private key ID and not the unique combination of `owner_id` and `item_id`?

Comment: From what data did you come to conclusion you can't store the same pairs of `owner_id` and `item_id` in `item_ownerships` if this table has its own PK not related to these fields?

Comment: Sequelize would generate `UNIQUE(owner_id, item_id)` upon the use of `belongsToMany` even though a PK existed in that table. I've found way to disable that but thank you greatly for attempting to help me with my `Circular dependency` issue

Answer (score 0):

According to sequelize documentation here https://sequelize.org/master/manual/constraints-and-circularities.html, Sequelize do not know which table to create first which happens when you use sequelize.sync() function to automatically create the tables and when you do have a cyclic dependency tables.
What sequelize suggests is to add `constraints: false` in your association by which sequelize will not try to put a foreign key constraint and will be able to create table without any confusion.
For now, to solve your problem, once sequelize creates the tables/you yourself create the table => you need to make  foreign keys and constraints on your own.
**OR**
We have a workaround if you still need some kind of automation

Wherever you do use sequelize.sync(), we can later add constraint(if not already present) by using queryInterface or raw query.

- Firstly add `constraint: false` to the 6 association that you make between characters and item_ownerships
- Then add this in sequelize.sync()

```js
// using lodash library to iterate over array of object to find a matching object
const _ = require('lodash');

/**
 *Sequelize object initialisation and other code
 */

sequelize.sync()
    .then(async () => {

        // https://sequelize.org/master/manual/query-interface.html
        const queryInterface = sequelize.getQueryInterface();

        // https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html
        const constraints = await queryInterface.getForeignKeyReferencesForTable('characters');
        // console.log('constraints', constraints);
        
        /**
         * Providing 2 methods below  to create constraint at runtime
         * Only Use 1 of them whichever suits your needs
         * Both of them does the same thing
         * Also we need to check first if constraint is not already present as
         * there *does not* exist a query like 'ADD CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS'
         * atleast in postgres which I was using
         */

        // checking if constraint does not exist
        if (!_.find(constraints, (constraint) => constraint.constraintName === 'character_primary_slot_item_owner_fk')) {
            console.log('adding constraint');

            // method 1 - using direct raw query
            const query_p = `ALTER TABLE "characters" ADD CONSTRAINT "character_primary_slot_item_owner_fk" FOREIGN KEY ("primary_slot") REFERENCES "item_ownerships" ("id");`
            await sequelize.query(query_p);

            // method 2 - using query interface function
            await queryInterface.addConstraint('characters', {
                type: 'FOREIGN KEY',
                fields: ['primary_slot'],
                name: 'character_primary_slot_item_owner_fk',
                references: {
                    table: 'item_ownerships',
                    field: 'id',
                }
            });
        }
        /**
         * Repeat `if` part for 2 other columns
         * OR make a function that does this
         */
        console.log('DB synced');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('error', err);
    });
```